# Odata : query url to aggregate multiple fields based on independent filters

Tags: sql, filter, aggregate, odata, odata-v4

I am having a SQL query to realise in Odata URL query -

```
SELECT col1,
SUM (CASE WHEN col2 = 'str' THEN 1 ELSE 0) display_col2,
SUM (CASE WHEN col3 = 'str' THEN 1 ELSE 0) display_col3
FROM table
GROUP BY col1;
```

But I am not able to do so. facing issue in execution.

Comment: Can you precise what is your exception ? Please [edit] your question to show your log !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select col1,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'str' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS display_col2,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN col3 = 'str' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS display_col3
FROM table
GROUP BY col1;
```

Comment: I want to convert the SQL to Odata url